Which Li-Po batteries to use?
I am working on my own handheld device and I would like to use a Li-Pol battery in the range of 1000mAh. I can get one of the li-po pouches with protection circuit in them and wires out, in which case I would have to cut the wires short and solder them directly to the PCB (there is not enough room for the extra wire and large connector that comes with the battery in my design), or I was thinking I can use a cell phone battery, such as Nokia's BL-5C. Then all I have to do is solder the connector on my PCB (and maybe add possibly extra protection circuit on the PCB in case the battery is not protected itself).
It feels using the cell phone battery is superior solution as the battery is cheaper and sturdier than the pouches, yet I can't find many DIY designs that would use cell-phone batteries. Am I missing something, or is cell phone battery good for DIY?
Thanks!
CLARIFICATION: Both battery types suit my needs as far as I can tell. To state the question clearly: What is worse: Buy a Li-po pouch battery and solder its wires directly to the PCB, or buy a cell-phone battery and add a protection circuit to my PCB?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Decisions are based on a set of criteria like a Zenn diagram with tradeoffs on capacity, cost, size , form, fit and functional life cycle, thermal effects.  If you want advice, you must state all the unwritten assumptions on requirements. Your technical question is missing.  There are many options Alkaline, NiMH, LiPo, Li Ion

@D.A.S. a "Zenn" diagram? Is that where you meditate on the overlap between the various tradeoffs... ?

All "must have requirements" must be met while "nice to haves" may be outside the common set.  @brhans Did I strain your imagination?

First, please understand that what you call a "lipo battery" is actually just a Li-ion battery that uses a Li-ion cell that happens to be in a pouch.
Second, you should know that a cell phone battery is either not protected (dangerous!) or it is but it requires an unknown to us communication link to turn on. In the first case, your plan to add a protector BMS on the PCB is good. But it's safer and easier to buy a protected Li-ion battery, a stand-alone one that doesn't need to receive a message to turn on.
Third, be aware that a Li-ion pouch cell will degrade is it is not constrained against expansion (in the worst case becoming a "spicy pillow).
Given the above, your best option is to buy a protected Li-ion battery that uses either a small Li-ion cylindrical cell (i.e. 18650) or a Li-ion pouch cell. I would recommend a cylindrical cell because it is inherently constrained. But, if you need something flatter, then go for a pouch cell, but make sure to add a mechanical constraint against expansion.

There are lithium polymer batteries and they are called Lipo's. They are hot batteries for discharge rates exceeding C50 and can be charged at 10C. Very popular in radio-controlled aircraft.

"they are called Lipo's" by hobbysist and vendors who cater to them. Professionals call them what they are: Li-ion pouch cells. And this is a professional web site.

This is not a professional site, and you're mistaken. Lithium polymer cells use polyethylene glycol, making them quite different from other lithium chemistries. They have extremely low internal resistance and high energy densities, making them unstable and dangerous. They come in coffee bags and rigid structures. All anyone has to do is look it up for themselves. Argue with this Andrea. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_polymer_battery   And if you don't like that then try https://www.androidauthority.com/lithium-ion-vs-lithium-polymer-whats-the-difference-27608/

@Dereck  I talk directly to the chemists and engineers who make the cells. They assure me that a pouch cell uses EXACTLY the same electrolyte, EXACTLY the same separator, EXACTLY the same electrode materials as small cylindrical and prismatic cells. The only difference is how they are wrapped and encased. I can't help it if a wikipedian doesn't know that. And the "Android authority" is not contradicting what I said, it is just using the term "Li-poly" instead of "Li-ion pouch cell". Other than that, the article is fine.
